# Mark seam breaks other uv island

Tags: uv

I would like if someone had same problem.
after editing Uv and made some separation, I found I need another seam to make the island to be straighten.

But if I mark new seam, It breaks other UV island which I arleady made...
I hope to know how I can avoid this problem. thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you need to do is **pin** your UV map:

- Let say you've made your first unwrap with a seam. Select all in the *UV Editor* and press <kbd>P</kbd> in order to pin.

[image]

- Create your second seam.

[image]

- In the object, select the part you want to unwrap again, in the *UV Editor* remove the pin for this part with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

[image]

- Unwrap again. In the *UV Editor*, it won't affect the pinned vertices, it will only affect the non-pinned vertices.

[image]

- Move and scale the new islands wherever you want in the *UV Editor*.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply. I could solve almost,but still some undefined edges got collapsed.... to solve it,I did "seams from island" from UV menu too. then it went all good.

Comment: oh ok good to know  ;)  not sure what it does though